# Difference between "lazyLoad" and "lazy" in react-navigation options

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I had a problem re-rendering my component on tabs change, and apparently adding `lazyLoad: true` to the navigation options solved it.

But I don't understand very well how it works...especially before that, I had another problem and adding `lazy: true` to options solved it.

so my question is, what is the difference between the two and how they work in react-navigation :)

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/214#issuecomment-304826301) "the property used to be called `lazyLoad` but now it's just called `lazy`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major releases of `react navigation`,
[react-navigation-v1](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.html) and [react-navigation-v2](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

When `react-navigation` loads up a navigator e.g `TabNavigator`, it tries to render all the screens inside that navigator.

For `react-navigation-v1`: When the `TabNavigator` is mounted on the screen, It tries to push all the screens/components configured inside itself at once to the UI. So to avoid this behavior, in the `TabNavigator` options, `lazyLoad: true` or `lazy: true` is passed, so the Screens/Components can be rendered as required.

Until `react-navigation 1.0.0-beta9`, `lazyLoad: true` was used, but since it is stable now, `lazy: true` is used.

For `react-navigation-v2`: `TabNavigator` and `createTabNavigator` are deprecated, you will always get that yellow screen error, so use `createBottomTabNavigator` and/or `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` . The `lazy` option works with `TabNavigator` and `createTabNavigator`, `createBottomTabNavigator` has `lazyLoading` option built in, but `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` seems to buggy, the `lazy` option does not work.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Please check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849938/942239) I have written complete code there

This is the important part

```
  lazy={true}
  optimizationsEnabled={true}
  tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
```