# How to "lazy load" tab navigator screens now that lazy has been removed from react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The maintainers of react-navigation have removed 'lazy: true' from the library, causing all tabs to attempt to render at once (and fetches previously controlled by lazy now firing out of order).

In order to maintain similar functionality, how do you force a wait on a tab screen to not load or call fetch calls prior to being focused for the first time?

Comment: Have they? According to docs, it's still a prop: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig . 

EDIT: After some more searching I've found that they did remove it, but added it back, see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems they did remove it, but have decided to add it back in v 1.1.2

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v1.1.2

Thus, you should be able to pass `lazy={true}` in your `TabNavigatorConfig` object, and then tabs will not be rendered before they are active. To further optimize memory usage, you can couple this with `removeClippedSubviews` to free memory from inactive tabs.

Comment: This is great, thank you!  I hadn't caught this update as I had fixed development at 1.0.22.

Comment: For thee who may be reading this in 2023 onward, the [`removeClippedSubviews`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/tab-navigator/#tabnavigatorconfig) was supported only up to and including v2.

Since v6, you may want to take a look at the [`ResourceSavingView`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#resourcesavingview) which uses the [`removeClippedSubviews`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#removeclippedsubviews) internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LazyLoading` from [react-navigation-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-utils)

Answer (score 1):

React-navigation now suports `withNavigationFocus` [wrapper](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html).
You can use it to wrap the screen you want to prevent updating when it is not focused.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class LazyScreen extends React.Component {
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     return nextProps.isFocused;
   }

  render() {
    return <Text>{this.props.isFocused ? 'Focused' : 'Not focused' </Text>;
  }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(LazyScreen);
```

P.S. if you use Redux just do
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withNavigationFocus(LazyScreen));`

Comment: can you explain more on this  or point me to a link where it explains in depth? Please explain how we can use this for typescript definition?

Comment: For thee who may be reading this **in 2023/v6 onward**, the [`withNavigationFocus`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation-focus/) HOC was supported only up to and including v4 (also in v5 with the [`@react-navigation/compat`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/compatibility/)).

Since v6, you may want to take a look at the [`ResourceSavingView`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#resourcesavingview) which uses the [`removeClippedSubviews`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#removeclippedsubviews) internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
lazy={true}
  optimizationsEnabled={true}
  tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
```

***the above code is important, try it***

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator();
const Stack2 = createStackNavigator();

const ProductsScreen = (props) => {
//
return (
<TabNavigator.Navigator
  lazy={true}
  optimizationsEnabled={true}
  tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
>
  <TabNavigator.Screen name="HOME" component={StackScreen1} />
  <TabNavigator.Screen name="SHOP" component={StackScreen2} />
</TabNavigator.Navigator>
);
};

const tabBarOptions = {
indicatorStyle: {
height: null,
top: 0,
backgroundColor: "#ccc",
borderBottomColor: "black",
borderBottomWidth: 3,
},
activeTintColor: "black",

style: {
backgroundColor: "red",
},
labelStyle: { fontSize: 13 },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const MyTab = TabNavigator({
    tab1:{screen:TabScreen1},
    tab2:{screen:TabScreen2}
}


class MainScreen extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            loading:true
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        //fetch login
        //set loading:false when fetch is done
    }

    render(){
        !this.state.loading && <MyTab/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new versions of React Navigation the `lazy` prop is set to `true` by default.

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#lazy