# How can I enable lazy on createMaterialTopTabNavigator react-navigation v4?

Tags: react-navigation

In react-navigation v3, `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` had the `lazy` option, on react-navigation v4, it's still available but it's not working, according to this [reply](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6174) on the github account, seems to be that it's only working again on react-navigation v5.
Anyone now how can I enable lazy load on react-navigation-tabs?

```
const CTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(BTabs, {
  // Default config for all screens',
  initialRouteName: AScreen',
  tabBarComponent: Header,
  swipeEnabled: false,
  lazy: true,
  backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
});
```

package.json

```
 "react-native": "0.60.4",
 "react": "16.8.6",
 "react-native-reanimated": "1.2.0",
 "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.1",
 "react-navigation": "4.0.5",    
 "react-navigation-tabs": "2.5.3",
 "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
```

Comment: that reply refers to lazy imports which is a different thing.

Comment: @satya164 you're right. The lazy load of the components in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator ` it's available ?

Comment: it should work with the version you're using. if not, please open an issue with a repro

Answer (score 0):

[use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849938/942239) I have written complete code there

```
  lazy={true}
  optimizationsEnabled={true}
  tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}
```