# React Navigation Tab Navigator dropped lazy loading (createMaterialTopTabNavigator)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

The deprecation of **createTabNavigator** and choice to omit lazy loading from **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** in React Navigation v2 has left us in a pickle. Each of our tabs triggers a significant request from the server, and the combination of running them all at once is not viable. We need a new solution, here are some ideas but nothing so far has worked:

1. **createBottomTabNavigator** still has lazy loading built in. We have considered using and restyling it live on the top. This seems somewhat dumb.
2. We have read vague posts about using a placeholder and listening for focus (**withNavigationFocus**), but we can't find a working example.
3. Perhaps **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** isn't the right solution here, and we should be looking into a different way to lazy load tabs?

Have you faced a similar problem with lazy loading react native tabs, and how did you handle it?

Comment: I have experienced the same issue. I wrote my experience [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622083/6409878)`